# Why do we Daven Yom tov Musaf on Shabbat Chol Hamoed and do Yom Tov Leining?

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, torah-reading, chol-hamoed, musaf

Why do we Daven Yom tov Musaf on Shabbat Chol Hamoed and do Yom Tov Leining? Based on תדיר ושאינו תדיר I would have thought we say regular Shabbat Mussaf with insertions for Yom Tov and Similarly continue with Parashat Hashavua just with the Yom Tov Maftir.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Consider registering your account to best utilise the site's features.

Comment: What are the Yom tov additions for musaf?

Comment: Wouldn't the same question apply on Shabbat on Yom tov? What does Chol hamoed have to do with anything

Comment: I move to close as unclear, since youve gotten answers so far to three different questions, not to mention my two previous comments

Comment: Addition to DoubleAA's comment - no one has answered your Torah reading concern. Perhaps, that should be separated. I sense that there is a different reasoning to the Torah reading.

Answer (score 1):

You mention that the reason you suspect we should use the *Shabbat* text of the *musaf* service is because of the *halakhic* principle called `תדיר ושאינו תדיר, תדיר קודם`. This principle means that when you have two *mitzvot* to do, one of which is done frequently and the other of which is done infrequently, all else being equal one should do the frequent *mitzvah* first.

An example of this is brought in the [Kitzur Shulchan Arukh 76:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.76.12?lang=bi) which says that if you delay in davening *musaf* until the time comes for *mincha* so you're left with needing to say both *tefilot*, you should say *mincha* first because we daven *mincha* every day and *tadir v'she'eino tadir, tadir kodem*.

This *halakhic* principle wouldn't seem to apply in this case because we only say the *tefilat musaf* once so there's no concept of "first" or "second" (although every time the day is mentioned, *shabbat* actually always **does** come before the *chag* so it seems the principle is adhered to there). The principle of *tadir* has nothing to do with which text should be used.

Comment: Hi Daniel. The answer is great as is. For my own info, can you provide a source that supports the definition that you described in your 2nd sentence. You cite an example, but not a source for that definition. You can decide if you want to include a link to that source in your answer.

Comment: @DanF My source is a simple translation of the words. I think one would need a source to show that it means anything other than what I've said.

Answer (score 0):

The musaf we pray include shabbat and chag hamatsot and shabbat (or hamanoach following Rashi and the Shulchan Aruch) is mentioned before chag hamatsot in each occurence, without any contradiction with the principle of tadir kodem.

See SA OC 490, 9:

> ובמוסף אומר סדר מוסף יום חול המועד, אלא שמזכיר של שבת, ואומר: "ותתן לנו את יום המנוח הזה ויום חג המצות הזה", וכן אומר: "את מוספי יום המנוח הזה ויום חג המצות הזה", וחותם "מקדש השבת וישראל והזמנים". ומפטירין "היתה עלי":‏
>
> ...   he say this day of musefey (plural of musaf)  ...

See Gemara Betsa 17b with the comment of Rashi:

> ובמוספין מתחיל כו' אלא בהא הלכתא כרבי דאמר אף חותם בה מקדש השבת ישראל 
>   והזמנים ...‏
>
> On musaf he begins (with the Sabbath [formula] and closes with the Sabbath [formula], and makes mention of the holiness of the day in the middle... Said Rav Huna: The halachah is not as that pair [of scholars]) but the Halacha is as Rabbi said, that he concludes mekaddesh Hashabbat, Israel Vehazzemanim

In conclusion, the Musaf is a double musaf of Shabbat and Yom Tov and Shabbat is mentioned before Yom Tov in each occurence that both are mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer

Musaph of Yom Tov is used throughout Yom Tov, whether it is Hol Hamo'ed or not. It has nothing to do with it being Shabbat. The reason seems simple. The Musaph prayer replaces the actual Musaph sacrifice. On any holiday, this Musaph sacrifice was offered throughout all the days of the holiday.

Of course, on Shabbat, we include the mentioning of the Shabbat Musaph offering along with the holiday one.

If your wondering why not use the Shabbat Musaph text and just include the paragraph for the Yom Tov Muspah offering (i.e. the one paragraph) - I would surmise that an integra; part of the holiday Musaph text includes mentioning of *aliyah laregel* - the mention of the "pilgrimage" - which is absent from the text of the Shabbat Musaph.

I'll have to research something that addresses the Torah reading.